# C# - Drawing a centered rectangle with Graphics in Windows Form doesn't give the expected result

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I made a little project to make some drawing tests.
I am under Visual Studio 2019 (Community Version) and I am using .Net Framework 4.7.2.

Here is the context: I made a Windows Form project. My form is fullscreen and borderless, and in this form, I have a `CenteredRectanglePanel` (which inherits from Panel). This panel takes all the space available in my form. So in theory, the panel has the same size as my screen (1920x1080)

What I want now is to draw a centered rectangle on my screen.

Here is the code I thought I could draw my centered rectangle :

```
public class CenteredRectanglePanel : Panel {

  public CenteredRectanglePanel(Control parent) { // The parent is my form
    var boundsX = parent.Bounds.X + (int) (parent.Bounds.Width * 0.1);
    var boundsY = parent.Bounds.Y + (int) (parent.Bounds.Height * 0.1);
    var boundsWidth = parent.Bounds.Width - 2 * boundsX;
    var boundsHeight = parent.Bounds.Height - 2 * boundsY;
    Bounds = new Rectangle(boundsX, boundsY, boundsWidth, boundsHeight);
    var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Aqua);
    CreateGraphics().FillRectangle(brush, Bounds);
  }

}
```

And here is the result on my screen :

[Here, the rectangle is not centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lph4.png)

It's not what I want. As you see, the rectangle is not centered. And the left space seems to be two times larger than the right space.

But, if I change the code for that :

```
public class CenteredRectanglePanel : Panel {

  public CenteredRectanglePanel(Control parent) { // The parent is my form
    var boundsX = parent.Bounds.X + (int) (parent.Bounds.Width * 0.1);
    var boundsY = parent.Bounds.Y + (int) (parent.Bounds.Height * 0.1);
    var boundsWidth = parent.Bounds.Width - 3 * boundsX;
    var boundsHeight = parent.Bounds.Height - 3 * boundsY;
    Bounds = new Rectangle(boundsX, boundsY, boundsWidth, boundsHeight);
    var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Aqua);
    CreateGraphics().FillRectangle(brush, Bounds);
  }

}
```

Here is the result :

[Here, the rectangle is centered correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ib0Ny.png)

I have now the expected result. All I had to do, it's to change the `2 * boundsX` and the `2 * boundsY` for `3 * boundsX` and `3 * boundsY`.

But why? I still don't understand. It's counter intuitive for me.

Comment: Just a moment, my screenshots did not upload correctly. I will check it out and update my post. EDIT : the post have been updated!

Comment: 1) Don't use `CreateGraphics()`. All drawing should be done in a handler for the `Paint` event, or in the `OnPaint()` override. 2) It is impossible to say for sure what the problem is, since you didn't provide a good [mcve] as is required for questions asking for help with debugging. However, your first version of the code would not be correct unless `parent.Bounds.X` and `...Y` are both 0, because the rectangle you're drawing will always be drawn relative to the current instance, not the parent (i.e. you can't use coordinates from the parent's coordinate space to construct the rect).

Comment: You're calculating the X and Y positions (the Offset) in relation to the `Parent.Bounds` (you should use the `ClientRectangle`), then Painting (don't use `CreateGraphics()`) a rectangle, which is offset in relation to the parent's bounds, inside the ClientArea of a Panel, using the same offset. So the initial calculated offset is duplicated: the first offset moves the Panel's bounds, then the same offset draws the rectangle using, again, the same offset, but in relation to the Panel's new bounds. So you actually Offset the drawing twice (that's why I'm repeating everything twice :)

Comment: So, you want to first relocate and resize the Panel, then simply fill it's ClientRectangle completely (the offset is at `(0,0)`). Use the Paint event (or, better, override the OnPaint method in this context), to draw your Graphics, using the provided `e.Graphics` object. Dispose of the disposable graphics objects you create (the Brush, here). -- Note that you could simply resize the Panel and move it, setting its BackColor. Unless you want the Panel to fill the Form. In this case, just offset the Rectangle and don't set the Bounds.